# GWT - Ads in IFRAME

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, adsense

Making Google Ads work with [GWT](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-examples/wiki/DemoGwtAdsene) is very hard in my experience, the only way I have displayed an ad is through a IFRAME.

Since this clearly disallowed by Google (or is it really?), what are the options to display the ad?

Is there any JavaScript technique to work-around this issue?